# How to remove "sub-lists" from a list?

Tags: python, list

I am having trouble creating a function since I want to be able to refer to the tuple and not the list which contains the tuples. Hence I have come to the conclusion that I want to get rid of the inner square brackets.

I have a list similar to this:
`List=[[(1,2),(3,4),(5,6)],[(1,2),(5,7),(3,8)],[...],[...]]`

So the question I am asking is how can I remove the inner `[ ]` so that I can just produce a single list of tuples.

Also, I am not sure if I am allowed to ask another question, but how would i also delete duplicates `(x,y)` entries in my new list?

I have not provided code for this since I know the problem for the code I have and I believe I would confuse people by including it. If however, you wish to see the code, or want me to clarify anything please let me know.

Comment: For reference, this is typically known at "flattening" the list. For the second question, a google search will lead you to many existing solutions.

Comment: @Carcigenicate that is indeed what I am looking for, thank you for pointing this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this has been asked and answered on here multiple times. The solution to the flattening problem would be as follows:

```
new_list = [tupl for l in List for tupl in l]
```